# How to insert Null value to DataTable using ItemArray

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have written code that is well tested for performance.

in the code I am spliting a comma seperated string and assigning it to ItemArray of a DataTable Row.

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
var itemArray = processedUliValue.Split(',');
dr.ItemArray = itemArray;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Later in the code I am converting these itemArray values to integer based on selected column names

there I am getting exception if any column is empty.

So I am looking for setting the empty values to null while assigning itemArray , I tried using DBNull.Value in comma seperated string but it did not took null, I tried null as well but that also not worked.

Is there any way to assign null using this comma seperated string to ItemArray?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like your column, which you're trying to store `DbNull.Value` to, doesn't allow nulls. This works for me:

```
        var dt = new DataTable
        {
            Columns =
                {
                    new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("FirstName", typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true },
                    new DataColumn("LastName", typeof(string)) { AllowDBNull = true },
                }
        };

        var row = dt.NewRow();

        row.ItemArray = "1,,Jones".Split(',').Select(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)s).ToArray();

        dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I will try it , but it seems this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check whether column value is empty before converting it to int? It seems to be simpler that way.

Comment: For that I've to write additional code to split the string and assign each column a value and check for null, I have many columns and I am looking for simpler way to do this